# show and hide admob banner in unity canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I am trying to destroy/hide an AdMob banner when I exit canvas in Unity

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class ads : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private BannerView bannerView;

    void Start() {
        bannerView = new BannerView ("ca-app-pub-1234567890", AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build ();
        bannerView.LoadAd(request);
        bannerView.Show();
    }

    void OnDestroy() {
        bannerView.Destroy();
    }
}
```

I add the code to the canvas and it shows the banner without a problem, but when I close the canvas (click at button) the banner remains there.
Any ideas how to solve this problem? `OnDestroy()` doesn't really work here since all happens in one scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one day of struggle I came up with a solution

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class ads : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private BannerView bannerView;

    void Start() {
        bannerView = new BannerView ("ca-app-pub-1234567890", AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build ();
        bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    }
    void Update() {
        if (GameObject.FindWithTag ("pan1") == null)
            bannerView.Hide ();
        else
            bannerView.Show ();
    }
}
```

I tagged an object in canvas "pan1" and the banner shows only when it should.
I know that this might not be a perfect solution so feel free to alter it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `bannerView.hide()` when you want to hide it.

Comment: I mentioned that adding `bannerView.Hide()` in the same scene doesn't really work. I am sorry for this silly question but I am not good at C#

Comment: where in the scene did you add it?

Comment: I added it to the level select object. when I select a level canvas appear with ads but when I close it the add remains